# css class not taking effect after changing nativeElement.className

Tags: css, angular-material

So I'm writing an angular app and I'm trying to re-style a mat-form-field.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field  #matFormField class="example-full-width" >
     <input #autocompleteInput type="text" placeholder="Enter {{searchBy.value}}" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto"  (keyup.enter)="onEnter()">
     <fa-icon  [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>
     <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of autocompleteList" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="autocompleteSelected($event)">
             {{option[searchBy.value]}}
         </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('matFormField', { static: false, read: ElementRef}) formField: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.formField.nativeElement.children[0].children[0].children[0].className = 'mat-form-field-infix-fix';
}
```

SCSS:

```
mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-form-field-infix-fix {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

fa-icon {
  float: right;
}
```

and I can see that the className is definitely applied:

[image: screen capture of web developer tools inspecting div showing div.mat-form-field-infix-fix]

but for some reason the css isn't:

[image: missing css in developer tools]

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're running into View Encapsulation discussed [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles). Notable points:

> As discussed earlier, component CSS styles are encapsulated into the component's view and don't affect the rest of the application.

And the earlier discussion in the Style Scope section:

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.
>
> They are not inherited by any components nested within the template
>   nor by any content projected into the component.

So, to get your css to effect a nested components styling you have a few options:

1. Change the view encapsulation setting
2. Put this styling in the global style sheet of your application
3. In the component's css, use special [piercing rules](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) such as `::ng-deep` (useful, but Angular team has deprecated these without providing a good alternative)

Answer (score 0):

[Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) will be a direct cause of this problem.

Check the component's decorator for encapsulation which changes the default CSS strategy:

> ViewEncapsulation.Emulated    (default) Angular modifies the component's
> CSS selectors so that they are only applied to the component's view
> and do not affect other elements in the application, emulating Shadow
> DOM behavior. For more details, see Inspecting generated CSS.

In Angular, don't use **document** methods to work with the DOM.

1. Use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) to access DOM but never to update the DOM.
2. Use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to access and or update the DOM.

My notes on the matter (hope this helps someone)

```
// document methods vs Renderer2 and ElementRef
constructor( private eRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2){  }

// let elem = document.createElement('div');
let elem = this.renderer.createElement("div") as HTMLDivElement;
// or Angular's template ids <div #elem>
@ViewChild('elem', { static: true }) elem!: ElementRef;

// check for classnames
this.elm.nativeElement.classList.contains('className');

// elem.classList.add('class-name');
this.renderer.addClass(this.eRef, 'class-name');

// elem.classList.remove('class-name');
this.renderer.removeClass(this.eRef, className);

// elem.setAttribute('class', 'class-name'); // to add the class attribute and add a single class, removes others
// if you need to set a property or an attribute whose name is not statically known, use the renderer.setProperty() or renderer.setAttribute() method.
this.renderer.setProperty(this.eRef, 'innerHTML', '<h1>Hello world</h1>');

this.renderer.setAttribute(this.eRef, 'height', '501px');

// elem.style.color = 'white';
this.renderer.setStyle(this.eRef, 'color', 'white');

// elem.appendChild(line);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.eRef, elem); // add the element to the DOM

// this.elem.classList.contains(class); // test for a classname on an element
// this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(span); // remove the element with native JS
// (<Element>this.elem.parentNode).classList.add('active'); // force TS to see element type (not a node)
// (<Element>this.elem.parentNode).classList.remove('active');
```